# Shortcuts on Host istead of VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization

The host is Ubuntu 22.04,  the VMware Player 17 and the VM is the latest Kali Linux.

The problem is that every shortcut I give in the VM, will be catch by host instead of the VM. For example I want to open a terminal in Kali using shortcut, but in Ubuntu will be open. 90% of my work, I am using only keyboard so it's impossible for me not to have my shortcuts.

I searched for everything but couldn't find anything related. The thing is that I have an older machine with Ubuntu 18.04, VMware 17 and exact the same Kali image and my everyday working Windows machine with the same image again. It seems that Ubuntu 22.04 has the issue with any image that I tried.